# How to resolve my timeout during import of my Drupal database using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: database

I downloaded my Drupal database (in MySQL format, and using phpMyAdmin) from my new web site. I am attempting to import it using phpMyAdmin on my local Win 7 computer running Acquia Dev Desktop. It generates a script timout on Drupal table `cache_menu` with 31 rows imported.

I started the import again. This time the row count in cache_menu is 62. I've been doing this for hours! The row count goes from 31, 62, 93, 124, 155, 186, ... about 30 rows each time. The odd thing is that only 66 rows exist in `cache_menu` on bluehost.

Here are the versions of software involved:

Bluehost mysql version 5.5.42-37.1-log InnoDB
Acquia mysql version 5.5.42-37.1 InnoDB

Bluehost phpmyadmin version 3.5.8.2
Acquia phpmyadmin version 4.3.7

I tried the suggestions as described in "[Maximum execution Time in PhpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263680/maximum-execution-time-in-phpmyadmin)". Unfortunately, these suggestions resulted in Internal Server Error.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Explaining why importing a database with phpMyAdmin times out is off-topic here. It doesn't time out because the database is one used from Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Skip processing rows in cache tables

For any of the cache-tables, there is no need to actually import them in your dev environment. So it is OK to just skip those rows during your import. That might help to get around this issue. FYI: clearing the cache in the site where you are exporting from, before performing the export is another way to avoid such rows being imported (might help also).

## Use module Backup and Migrate

Another possible work around, you may want to consider using the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.

Refer to the readme.txt that comes with the module for details to get you going.

Your local environment is Win 7, though your hosted website probably runs in "some other OS" (Linux? Something else? consider clarifying in your question also ...). So that implies potential extra challenges (because of differences in the OS-es. I've had good experiences with Backup and Migrate between different OSes, which didn't cause any problems (worked fine) in situations where the typical MySql export / import failed before.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am actually watching a video about Backup & Migrate right now. I am curious about the behavior of import as I documented above.

Comment: OK. I will drop this question and work on using Backup and Migrate.